# Find the circumference in terms of r

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[image: question]

I've managed to work out that the length $AB$ is $\sqrt{3} r$

I'm getting completely different answers from the correct one for part **b** of the question: $\sqrt{3}\pi r$

I'm not even $100%$ sure if it is referring to the circumference of the major or minor segment. I've tried to work out both and still don't get that answer. Any tips?

Cheers!!

Comment: Imagine that the part of the ball above water is a desert island. Then the question is asking for the length of the coastline.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, note that the portion (circumference) of ball is $\frac{2\pi/3}{2\pi}$ of the total circumference. Thus, arc $AB=2\pi r\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}\pi r$.

P.S.: The object here is a ball i.e., a sphere. Thus, length $AB$ doesn't makes any sense. $AB$ can have infinitely many values. Nevertheless, I considered it a circle, as you did for the first part. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the wording of the problem. Once you find the length AB you can very easily use the formula $\pi\times \mbox{diameter}$ to find the circumference the question refers to. The diameter is the length AB; simply multiply it by $\pi$ to answer part b.

Comment: the diagram refers to a cross-section of the ball. Also AB can only be √3 if we are taking it as the line AB, not the arc AB. How do you know the diameter is length AB? That would mean AB is 2r?

Comment: Yes $AB$ is a line, not an arc. You worked out the distance $AB$ using trigonometry, $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac{x}{r}$. In this case $x=\frac{1}{2}*AB$. Now remember $r$ is not the radius of the cross-section we need to find the circumference of, $r$ is the radius of the entire sphere, a different distance. So, use your answer from part a to determine what is the radius(or diameter in this case) of the circle of interest for part b. To visualize this circle, it is described as a circle that goes through both points $A$ and $B$. So the distance $AB$ must be the diameter.